# How can I mock something that "does not implement" a particular method?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, amazon-web-services, rspec, cucumber

### The Background:

I'm trying to use cucumber to do some test-driven (or behavior-driven) development around an interface to AWS, in ruby.

So, I have a step definition that looks like this:

```
Then(/^the mock object should have had :(.*?) called, setting "(.*?)" to "(.*?)"$/) do |method, param, value|
  expect(@mock).to receive(method.to_sym).with(hash_including(param, value))
end
```

Where `@mock` was previously set using:

```
@mock = instance_double(AWS::AutoScaling::Client)
```

And where I invoke this step definition with a feature line like:

```
And the mock object should have had :update_auto_scaling_group called, setting "auto_scaling_group_name" to "Some-test-value"
```

When that step gets run, it gets the following error (leaving out the full error, as I believe this is the most relevant part):

```
  AWS::AutoScaling::Client does not implement: update_auto_scaling_group (RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError)
```

I see that indeed, the [checks that RSpec runs](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/master/lib/rspec/mocks/method_reference.rb#L73) (as traced back [from where the `RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError` gets thrown](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/master/lib/rspec/mocks/any_instance/recorder.rb#L222)) are at least correctly reporting the information that they get from the class:

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'aws-sdk'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> klass = AWS::AutoScaling::Client
=> AWS::AutoScaling::Client
[3] pry(main)> klass.public_method_defined? "update_auto_scaling_group"
=> false
[4] pry(main)> klass.private_method_defined? "update_auto_scaling_group"
=> false
[5] pry(main)> klass.protected_method_defined? "update_auto_scaling_group"
=> false
```

And yet, if we ask an actual instance, it lets us know that this is a method it would respond to:

```
[6] pry(main)> x = klass.new
=> #<AWS::AutoScaling::Client::V20110101>
[7] pry(main)> x.respond_to? "update_auto_scaling_group"
=> true
```

Even while it doesn't say that about just anything:

```
[8] pry(main)> x.respond_to? "bogus"
=> false
```

### First questions:

So... is this a bug in [the AWS::AutoScaling::Client code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-core-ruby/blob/master/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/autoscaling.rb) (or really, probably [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-core-ruby/blob/master/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core.rb#L251)), for not defining the methods in a way that the extant checks (`{public,private,protected}_method_defined?`) would come back true?

Or perhaps a bug in RSpec's "doubles", for not doing all the checking it could do to try to find out that this is indeed a method that's callable in an instance of that class?

Or perhaps it's simply something that I'm doing wrong here?  Other?

### More generally:

How can I write tests for the code I'm writing, to ensure that it's making calls to what will be an `AWS::AutoScaling::Client` instance, with the correct parameters (as defined in several checks that I have)?  Are there alternate ways I can write my step definitions that would make this work? Alternative ways to create my mock objects?  Other?

Answer (score 2):

I've found a way to dynamically mix in the methods I needed to mock

You could do this with empty methods and then stub them, or just include the stubs in the mixin

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "users/sessions/new.html.erb", :type => :view do


  it "displays login form" do

    module DeviseUserBits
      def resource
        @_DeviseUserBitsUser ||= User.new
      end
      def resource_name
        :user
      end
      def devise_mapping
        Devise.mappings[:user]
      end
    end

    view.class.include DeviseUserBits

    render

    expect(rendered).to match /form/

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It just adds methods on/after instantiating. It's pretty legal, all ruby classes/objects are open.

Proper answer - you do not want to test what you are trying to test in duck-typed language with open classes and objects. It just does not make sense.

Comment: Wait, so... is it wrong to try to be testing that my code is actually calling the `AWS::AutoScaling::Client` object with certain parameters?  What would you propose doing instead?  I'd like to make sure that the behavior of *my* code is correct.  Is the answer to simply not use `instance_double`, and instead use some other type of mock object?  or... ??

Comment: you can mock in method you need into your @mock explicitly. or take a look how they implemented rails or fg helpers and make your own.

Comment: or just use stock aws-sdk mocks http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx2SU6TYJWQQLC3/Stubbing-AWS-Responses

Comment: "Unfortunately, this approach stubs responses, but it does not mock AWS services." - I've tried a bit, and I'm failing to quite see how to use this to get the mocks I want.

Comment: @iced Also, there is the newer response stubbing feature for the v2 AWS SDK for Ruby: http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx15V81MLPR8D73/Client-Response-Stubs

Answer (score 0):

The version 1 AWS SDK for Ruby uses `#method_missing` as a delegate for building and sending requests. The methods a client responds to are defined in an API definition. This eliminates boiler-plate code, but causes problems if you are trying to reflect the available methods at runtime.

Option A: Use a regular double and apply your assertions on the test double.

Option B: Use the mocking feature of the SDK via AWS.stub! When stubbing is enabled, all clients constructed will respond to their regular methods, but will return dummy responses (empty hashes and arrays). This approach provides the useful ability to specify the data to return from a stub. You can even create a stub response for the express purpose of returning from an assertion.

Going with Option B:

```
# use `:stub_requests` or call Aws.stub!
as = AWS::AutoScaling::Client.new(:stub_requests: true)

# validates parameters as normal, but returns empty response data
as.update_auto_scaling_group(auto_scaling_group_name: 'name')
#=> {}

# You can access the stub response for any operation by name:
stub = as.stub_for(:describe_auto_scaling_groups)
stub.data[:auto_scaling_group_names] = ["Group1", "Group2"]

# Now calling that operation will return the stubbed data
resp = as.describe_auto_scaling_groups
resp.auto_scaling_group_names
#=> ['Group1', 'Group2']
```

If you need to assert a method is called against the client, you can do so normally, returning the stubbed response:

```
expect(@client).to receive(:describe_auto_scaling_groups).
  with(hash_including(param, value)).
  and_return(@client.stub_for(:describe_auto_scaling_groups))
```